# Laravel Eloquent: function in where clause

Tags: php, eloquent

I want my SQL to look like:

```
SELECT ptype, sum(money) FROM `payments` WHERE YEAR(created_at) = 2016 GROUP BY ptype
```

I am struggling with putting "**YEAR(created_at) = 2016**" into Laravel Eloquent query builder...

Tried different options:

```
$data = \EPA\Models\Payments::where('YEAR(created_at)', '=', intval($period))
->groupBy('ptype')->get();
```

and with DB::raw:

```
$data = \EPA\Models\Payments::where(DB::raw('YEAR(created_at)'), '=', intval($period))
->groupBy('ptype')->toSql();
```

Which gives me error

```
 SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'YEAR(created_at)'
 in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `payments` where `YEAR(created_at)` = 2016 group by `ptype`)
```

or SQL like:

```
select * from `payments` where YEAR(created_at) = ? group by `ptype`
```

that is also not suitable form me, because third parameter of where clause is replaced with "?" suddenly...

In fact, the issues are that in one case it escapes YEAR(...) and MySQL thinks it is a column, and in second way Eloquent places "?" instead of year.

Can somebody help to integrate this where clause with function into eloquent...? What is the best way of doing this? (I need it for my report script)

Comment: `$data = \EPA\Models\Payments::whereRaw("YEAR(created_at) = ". intval($period))->groupBy('ptype')->get();`

Comment: OMG! thank you, it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like **[Mark Baker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker)** answered in comments, I can use "whereRaw" for the solution:

```
$data = \EPA\Models\Payments::selectRaw('ptype, sum( money )')
->whereRaw('YEAR(created_at) = '. intval($period))
->groupBy('ptype')->get();
```